# Removing Fedora 13 and installing ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, installation, grub2

I have used 10.04 for a while using the wubi installation with Windows XP.

I then uninstalled it and gave Fedora 13 a try (on its own partitions).

Now I would like to completely get rid of Fedora and install ubuntu 10.10 (not using the wubi, but the real thing this time), so I will have a dual boot with my XP.

What's the best way to do that?

The only caveat is that I don't have the XP CD in hand (I know it's needed sometimes to run `fixmbr` from recovery console to get rid of grub). I can ask for the CD from our admin but it would take a couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu into the partition that is currently fedora either with a CD, or with a [usb stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). You can download the necessary iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download. The [Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) has more information how to install dual-boot

To fix the MBR you can use utilities independent from the XP CD http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ is just one of the examples.

Comment: Great. It will format and remove all the fedora stuff? Also, I think fedora actually takes a couple of partitions (which I can't see from windows): one for `/`, one for `swap` etc.

Comment: Yes. if you install into the partition which contains fedora, it will reformat the filesystem and there is nothing left from fedora. Ubuntu also needs a swap partition, and you can partition the Ubuntu system theoretically the same way as your fedora system is. Or, you can just delete all the fedora partitions and let the Ubuntu installer do its magic with the free space on the disk to create its own partitions.